# Navigate to record page, how to get the ID of the record?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

I'm trying to insert the correct attribute to navigate to the record page.
If I insert the ID hard-coded, it navigates successfully...

The function name is Handlenavigate at the end of the code.

Here is the code:

```javascript
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
// import server side apex class method 
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/customSearchSobjectLWC.getContactList';
// import standard toast event 
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class customSearch extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @track contactsRecord;
    searchValue = '';

    // update searchValue var when input field value change
    searchKeyword(event) {
        this.searchValue = event.target.value;
    }

    // call apex method on button click 
    handleSearchKeyword() {

        if (this.searchValue !== '') {
            getContactList({
                    searchKey: this.searchValue
                })
                .then(result => {
                    // set @track contacts variable with return contact list from server  
                    this.contactsRecord = result;
                    console.log("this", result)
                })
                .catch(error => {

                    const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error',
                        variant: 'error',
                        message: error.body.message,
                    });
                    this.dispatchEvent(event);
                    // reset contacts var with null   
                    this.contactsRecord = null;
                });
        } else {
            // fire toast event if input field is blank
            const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                variant: 'error',
                message: 'Search text missing..',
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
    handleNavigate() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: result.id,
                actionName: 'view',
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I`ve fixed it,
added - event.target.value to the recordId attr` and added the value of contact.id to the html button.